# Pandas Dataframe Mul on Multiindex

Tags: pandas

I have a Dataframe with a multi index, df

```
               'A'     'B'
1/1/12  T1     100     200
1/2/12  T1     40       20
1/3/12  T2     50       40
```

I then have a lookup table, lookup_table

```
     A     B
T1   0.5   0.25
T2   2      4

cols=['A','B']
```

I wanted to multiply the dataframe by the lookup_table based on the second index match.

So far I have this; but not working

```
df[cols].reindex(df.index,level=1).mul(lookup_table[cols])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just do:

```
df.mul(lookup_table, level=1)
```

Output:

```
               A      B
1/1/12 T1   50.0   50.0
1/2/12 T1   20.0    5.0
1/3/12 T2  100.0  160.0
```